# Android: Thread and a NotFoundException inside of it

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a problem with a NotFound resource exception. I'm sure that my resource-id exactly the same which I set but it fails anyway!
It's an interesting thing, because the first line with the "findViewById( R.id.editText1 )" executes well and I see the label "start!" in the editText1, but the second one inside the Thread - fails with:

```
09-29 00:17:45.103: E/AndroidRuntime(347): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

Can anyone help me with this sort of problem?
Here is a code:

```
EditText editText = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.editText1 );
editText.setText( "start!" );

final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

            final int value = i;

            try {

                Thread.sleep( 1000 );

            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

           handler.post( new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {

                   EditText editText = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.editText1 );
                   editText.setText( value );

               }

           } );

        }

    }

};

Thread thread = new Thread( runnable );
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is an integer value. Passing an integer into the `setText` method will attempt to find a `String` from your strings.xml file by resource ID. If you want to display a numeral, you'll need to parse it as a `String`: `Integer.toString(value)`